# Plotting a list of hours

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, ticker, hour

Ok, I searched a lot about it but still I didn't get it quite well...
Suppose I have:

```
listHours = ['00:00:000-10:00:000', '10:00:000-20:00:000', '20:00:000-30:00:000',    '30:00:000-40:00:000', '40:00:000-50:00:000', '50:00:000-00:00:000']
listNumbers = ['0.01', '0.02', '0.03', '0.05', '0.05', '0.03']
```

and I want:

```
plt.plot(listHours, listNumbers)
plt.show()
```

Matplotlib is not accepting this listHours ("ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 00:00:000-10:00:000") when I use ticks I get this error: "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number" I don't know if it's because I'm using this ticks thing wrong or whatever... any idea? I'm kinda frustrated here.

Thanks already.

Comment: Why are your hours in the format `"hr:min:sec - hr:min:sec"`? Shouldn't they just be `"hr:min:sec"`? For single hours (`hr:min:sec`) you can do `matplotlib.dates.datestr2num( <hour string> )` to convert it to something matplotlib can interpret.

Comment: So... I didn't choose this. The data came to me like that, god knows why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `xticks` command to do so. See the following snippet -

```
>>> listHours = ['00:00:000-10:00:000', '10:00:000-20:00:000', '20:00:000-30:00:000','30:00:000-40:00:000', '40:00:000-50:00:000', '50:00:000-00:00:000']
>>> listNumbers = ['0.01', '0.02', '0.03', '0.05', '0.05', '0.03']
>>> listNumbers = [float(elem) for elem in listNumbers]  # Convert to a list of floats.
>>> plt.plot(listNumbers)
>>> plt.xticks(range(len(listHours)), listHours, size='small')
>>> plt.show()
```

It gives you a figure like this

[image: Plot figure]

Comment: Did you convert `listNumbers` to a list of numbers to get that plot?

Comment: I missed that, but it seems to plot the lines fine. I'll convert it to a list of numbers.

Comment: yaaaay! I actually tried to do something like that, but I believe my yAxis was wrong. Thanks a lot!